# Nginx conditional client certificate authentication

Tags: ssl, nginx, configuration, ip, certificate

I am attempting to proxy traffic using Nginx. I have a server block in the configuration listening on HTTPS, and it is both supplying a valid certificate and checking the client certificate (2-way ssl). This setup works, but I want to be able to allow our developers to hit the server *without* the client certificate verification (since they obviously wont have it). The config I was working with before was:

```
server {
    listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
    server_name  api.website.com;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
    underscores_in_headers on;

    ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/private/ServerCert.pem";
    ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/ServerCert.pem";
    ssl_client_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/ClientCert.pem";
    ssl_verify_client on;
    ssl_verify_depth 2;
    ssl_dhparam "/etc/pki/nginx/dhparams.pem";
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_timeout  1m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:SEED:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!RSAPSK:!aDH:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA:!SRP;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location /tomcat/endpoint {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/tomcat-war;
        proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
    }
}
```

Again, this works, but effectively locks access except to certs that I add to the client certificate store. One solution would be to make an internally signed certificate and add that to the store, then distribute to our devs, but I would rather have the devs excluded from such checks based on IP address. I managed to do that by changing ssl_client_verify to optional and the location block to the following:

```
location /tomcat/endpoint {
  set $allowed 9;
  if ($ssl_client_verify != "SUCCESS") { set $allowed 1;}
  if ($not_internal_ip) { set $allowed  "${allowed}1"; }
  if ($allowed = 11) {
      return 403;
  }
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/tomcat-war;
  proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
}
```

where $not_internal_ip is set as a geo block like so:

```
geo $not_internal_ip {
  default 0;
  10.0.0.0/8 1;
  172.16.0.0/12 1;
  192.168.0.0/16 1;
}
```

Even though this works, I am concerned that the logic depends on so many if statements, which are [notoriously dangerous](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) in Nginx config files.

If this way of using if statements in the location block safe? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this without if statements also using maps

```
geo $internal_ip {
  default no;
  10.0.0.0/8 yes;
  172.16.0.0/12 yes;
  192.168.0.0/16 yes;
}

map $internal_ip$ssl_client_verify $request_allowed {
  ~* "^yes" yes;
  "noSUCCESS" yes;
  default no;
}

map $request_allowed $proxy_pass_url {
   yes  "http://localhost:8080/tomcat-war/$request_uri";
   no   "/access-denied";
}

location /tomcat/endpoint {
   proxy_pass $proxy_pass_url;
   proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
}

location /access-denied {
   return 403;
}
```

PS: I have not tested above config, but I have used similar approach in past

Comment: I really like where this is going, and I see how it could work, but how can it be adapted to multiple locations? I didn't say so in the original post, but I'm actually proxying for a few different wars based on the URI. I suppose I could replace the locations with rewrite rules, but I would prefer to have separate location blocks.

Comment: You can either use one if on `$request_allowed` and use that or else you will have to change `map $request_allowed $proxy_pass_url` to `map $request_allowed$request_uri $proxy_pass_url` and then have patterns inside the map to point to different war urls

Comment: By the way, I tested this and it works. The only thing that needed to change was the regex expression (should be ~*^yes all-together). I also opted for the single if statement in the location block. By matching the negative condition and returning 403, it shouldn't break. Thanks for your help!